# How to set up az cli concrete version in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

After last updates of Azure DevOps
our pipelines stopped working.
I am using [`AZURE CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) tasks.
Investigation shows that `az cli` was updated to `2.2.0`, but nothing was changed on our side.

```sh
/usr/bin/az --version
azure-cli                          2.2.0
```

And some `az cli` operations starts to print warnings.
`Warnings` by default are redirected in `bash` to error stream,
so I end up with:

```sh
Error: The process '/bin/bash' failed because one or more lines were written to the STDERR stream
```

How to set up concrete version of `az cli` for my pipelines?
I want pipelines to be stable with Azure DevOps updates.

Comment: You can install the concrete cli version or [update it to latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops#for-linux-azure-pipelines-steps-linuxyml).

Comment: `az cli` is preinstalled and I can't e.g. downgrade. 
My scripts are written using concrete version of `az cli`. After a while default `az cli` version has bump up and my pipeline stopped working. 
I want to set up `az cli` version and decide by myself when I am ready to go up.

Comment: Another option for the specific symptom is to add the option --only-show-errors to your az cli commands, this will prevent warnings being written to stderr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set up az cli concrete version in Azure DevOps

To resolve the error, please try to run the task again with the option "**Fail on Standard Error**" **unchecked**:

[image]

Besides, I am afraid there is no such out of box way to set up concrete version of `az cli`. Neither can I install an old version in an agent that already has the latest version az cli, either through python commands or chocolate packages:

python commands:

```
pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
```

This command line only install the latest version of `az cli`. Since I do not have the old version url, I could not test if it works with python command to install the old version az ci when there is a latest version already installed.

Then I test it by the chocolatey package:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/azure-cli/2.1.0#individual

```
choco install azure-cli --version=2.1.0 --force
```

But, this installation command still fails due to the existence of a latest version package.

Check [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6554) for some more details.

Alternatively, you could set up [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to build your project, and install the old version azure-cli by the choco package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Leo for a hint. I don't want to uncheck `Fail on Standard Error` while the rest of the pipeline doesn't make sens when this step is failing.

Comment: @wolszakp, Be able to understand your choice. But just like what I have test, it seems we could not set up az cli version at this moment, since we do not have the url for specify version az cli to install. You could submit your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps. Or we could set up our private agent.

Comment: Thanks @Leo for your support and fast reaction. I really like Azure DeOps. I am also impressed how fast it is developing. 
Here is suggestion:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/960733/set-up-fixed-az-cli-version-in-my-pipeline.html

Answer (score 7):

When working with Azure DevOps Hosted agents, Some software's installed on the machine automatically. The full list can be found [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) Ubuntu.

One of the Softwares is `Azure CLI:Latest`. Therefore, in case you want to downgrade you need to install a new version. The repo is removed after the [initial installation](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/discussions/5822#discussioncomment-3030703) so you will need to re-add that first:

```bash
AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" |
 sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list

AZ_VERSION=2.2.0
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=$AZ_VERSION-1~$UBUNTU_CODENAME
```

Comment: nice, just FYI this command works if you are using image "ubuntu-18.04", if you are using "ubuntu-20.04", change "bionic" to "focal"

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is not supported. 
I've created suggestion to add this feature:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/960733/set-up-fixed-az-cli-version-in-my-pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

Please note, to get this solution to work, you need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Before

```
sudo apt install
```

Otherwise the downloaded lists of versions does not update, and apt install will report it can't find the version.